# Jetty Remote Debugging AWS EC2 server with eclipse doesn't hit breakpoint

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, amazon-ec2, jetty

I'm running jetty server on amazon ec2 using the following command line:

> java -Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n  -DDEBUG -DSTOP.PORT=6666 -DSTOP.KEY=pass -jar start.jar &

I opened port 8000 in the ec2 security group and I was able to connect to the remote server.

[image]

Then I toggled a few breakpoints but none of them hit.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do brand new breakpoints hit?

Comment: No, I've deleted all of them and re toggled them. Do I need to compile the server with debug symbols? I'm using "mvn compile" to compile my code.

Comment: I think so, otherwise there's no line information, right?

Comment: I read that "mvn compile" command compiles it with the debug symbols as a default behavior isn't it the case? If not, what command should I use to compile it with mvn?